# How to install Microsoft.ReportViewer 12.0.0.0 on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, windows-server-2016

I have a server machine whose operating system is Windows Server 2016 Standard. It has IIS 10.0 which is hosting ASP.NET sites. One site needs to display a report but it is giving this error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common,
> Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I install ReportViewer on this server?

Visual Studio installation is not allowed on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Visual Studio on the server. According to the requirements for then viewer runtime it states it does support Windows Server.

Try using this download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747